# How to refactor the below code in such a way that if I made changes in display_home_page method I need not to make changes in the process method

Tags: ruby

Below are two methods: 1 `display_home_page`: to display on the console, and 2 `process`: for calling the method based on user input on `choice` variable.

```
def display_home_page
  print "  1 My Timeline\n  2 tweet\n  3 Other's  Timeline\n  4 Retweet\n  5 Follow\n  6 My Wall\n  7 logout\nEnter your choice : "
end

def process(choice)
  if choice == "1"
    my_timeline
  elsif choice == "2"
    tweet
  elsif choice == "3"
    others_timeline
  elsif choice == "4"
    re_tweet
  elsif choice == "5"
    follow
  elsif choice == "6"
    my_wall
  else
    error_message
  end
end
```

Comment: Would you like to use Hash to hold the choice message pair?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
MAPPING = {
  '1' => 'My Timeline',
  '2' => 'Tweet',
  '3' => "Other's Timeline",
  '4' => 'Retweet',
  '5' => 'Follow',
  '6' => 'My Wall',
  '7' => 'logout'
}

def display_home_page
  MAPPING.each do |number, method|
    puts "  #{number} #{method}"
  end

  puts 'Enter your choice :'
end

def process(choice)
  method = MAPPING.fetch(choice, 'error_message')

  send(method.downcase.gsub(' ', '_').gsub("'", ''))
end
```